# Encrypted LVM shutdown

Tags: lvm, truecrypt

So I have two hard drives. The actual drives have been encrypted with TrueCrypt, and then the virtual encrypted devices have been combined into a volume group using LVM. Now TrueCrypt does not automatically mount my drives on startup (because it needs my password), so what happens if my server needs to be restarted? Should I just be able to mount the TrueCrypt volumes from command line and LVM will go on its happy way, or will I lose all my data because LVM will think all my drives have disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the answer to this a while ago but forgot to update here. To re-recognize LVM devices if they do not exist on startup, run the following commands:

- Scan for devices: `pvscan`
- Re-activate Volume Group: `vgchange -a y`
- Re-activate Logical: `lvchange -a y <your VG here>`

Then everything should be good.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case you can try the **vgimport** command to search for volume groups on your drives.

Answer (score 0):

LVM data is actually stored on disk (In the encrypted TrueCrypt volume in this case), you might need to execute some commands that make the server pick-up the LVM again after mounting the TrueCrypt disks, but I'm not 100% sure about that.